# Query Firestore document by user UID with AngularFire

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable, angularfire2

I need some basic 101 style advice here.
I've built an app using Angular 15, Firebase 9, AngularFire 7. I've got auth set up and can log in and do simple read/write operations.

Now I'm setting up a component and I want it to get `` fs.doc(`/users/${user.uid}`) ``. This will retrieve a doc from the `/users` collection and from that I'll push some data to my view.

Everything in AngularFire (I'm in compat mode) seems to be an Observable so to get the `uid` I have to subscribe to `auth.user`, then when I get a result I can use the UID to query the `/users` collection.

But I'd like to know what the best approach is here - do I subscribe to `auth`, then nest another subscription on the result?

```
auth.user.subscribe((user:User|null)=>{
   if(user){
      fs.doc(`/users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges().subscribe((data)=>{
         console.log(data)
      })
   }
})
```

Or do I store my UID in a service as a variable to use elsewhere? Or am I completely heading off into the weeds here?

Sorry for the vague, hand-wavey question. I've been Googling all evening and what I really need is just a good example app, or tutorial on best practice for working with AngularFire. Their docs aren't doing it for me and their examples just cover very basic single queries which I'm fine with.

Any advice? I'm terribly confused and I'm going to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting subscriptions is an anti-pattern, it should be avoided.
How about using RxJS `filter` and `switchMap`?

```
auth.user.pipe(
  filter(user => !!user),
  switchMap(user => fs.doc(`/users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges())
).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Depending on the context you might need to take care of unsubscribing to avoid memory leaks or use `take(1)` where needed.